# mongoose sort down from current element

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am attempting to create a photography website and want to add buttons to each photo which redirect to the next/previous one in the mongo database. This is what I have so far:

```
// NEXT PHOTO - shows next photo 
router.get("/:id/next", function(req, res){
    Photo.find({}).sort({ _id: 1 }).limit(1).then(function(docs){ 
        console.log(docs[0]._id)
        res.redirect("/photos/" + docs[0]._id)
    })
})

// PREVIOUS PHOTO - shows previous photo 
router.get("/:id/previous", function(req, res){
    Photo.find({}).sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(1).then(function(docs){ 
        console.log(docs[0]._id)
        res.redirect("/photos/" + docs[0]._id)
    })
})
```

This gives me the first or last item in the database and not the previous/next one. How do I have to modify `sort()` so that it only sorts below/above the current element? I am not using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To getting next records you should say:

```
    router.get("/:id/next", function(req, res){
    Photo.find({_id: {$gt: id}}).sort({_id: 1 }).limit(1)then(function(docs){ 
        console.log(docs[0]._id)
        res.redirect("/photos/" + docs[0]._id)
    })
})
```

and also for the previous item:

```
    router.get("/:id/next", function(req, res){
    Photo.find({_id: {$lt: id}}).sort({_id: -1 }).limit(1)then(function(docs){ 
        console.log(docs[0]._id)
        res.redirect("/photos/" + docs[0]._id)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

For the next photo `Photo.find({$gt: curId}).sort({ _id: 1 })`

For the previous photo `Photo.find({$lt: curId}).sort({ _id: -1 })`

Where `curId` is the current ID of the photo.